# Ruby MongodB - improving speed when working with multiple collections

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB with Ruby using `mongo` gem.

I have the following scenario:

1. for each document in a collection say `coll1`, look at `key1` and `key2`
2. search for document in another collection say `coll2` with matching values for `key1` and `key2`
3. if there is a match, add document fetched in #2 with a new key `key3` whose value be set to value of `key3` in the document referenced in #1
4. insert the updated hash into a new collection `coll3`

The general guideline with MongoDB has been to handle cross collection operations in application code.

So I do the following:

```
    client = Mongo::Client.new([ '127.0.0.1:27017' ], :database => some_db, 
                               :server_selection_timeout => 5)
    cursor = client[:coll1].find({}, { :projection => {:_id => 0} }) # exclude _id
    cursor.each do |doc|
        doc_coll2 = client[:coll2].find('$and' => [{:key1 => doc[:key1]}, {:key2 => doc[:key2] }]).limit(1).first # no find_one method
        if(doc_coll2 && doc[:key3])
            doc_coll2[:key3] = doc[:key3]
            doc_coll2.delete(:_id) # remove key :_id
            client[:coll3].insert_one(doc_coll2)
        end
    end
```

This works, but it takes a lot of time to finish this job - approximately 250ms per document in collection `coll1` or 3600s (1 hour) for ~15000 records, which seems a lot, which could be associated with reading the document one at a time, do the check in app code and then writing one doc at a time back to a new collection.

Is there a way to get this operation be done faster? Is the way I'm doing even the right way to do it?

**Example documents**

- coll1

  ```
  {
      "_id" : ObjectId("588610ead0ae360cb815e55f"),
      "key1" : "115384042",
      "key2" : "276209",
      "key3" : "10101122317876"
  }
  ```
- coll2

  ```
  {
      "_id" : ObjectId("788610ead0ae360def15e88e"),
      "key1" : "115384042",
      "key2" : "276209",
      "key4" : 10,
      "key5" : 4,
      "key6" : 0,
      "key7" : "false",
      "key8" : 0,
      "key9" : "false"
  }
  ```
- coll3

  ```
  {
      "_id" : ObjectId("788610ead0ae360def15e88e"),
      "key1" : "115384042",
      "key2" : "276209",
      "key3" : "10101122317876",
      "key4" : 10,
      "key5" : 4,
      "key6" : 0,
      "key7" : "false",
      "key8" : 0,
      "key9" : "false"
  }
  ```

Comment: could you provide sample documents from coll1 and coll2, and also sample expected results (the documents you want to insert in coll3) ?

Comment: added examples for coll1, coll2 and coll3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution would be to use aggregation instead, and do this in one single query:

- perform a join on key1 field with `$lookup`
- unwind the array with `$unwind`
- keep doc where `coll1.key2 == coll2.key2` with `$redact`
- reformat the document with `$project`
- write it to coll3 with `$out`

so the query would be :

```
db.coll1.aggregate([
    { "$lookup": { 
        "from": "coll2", 
        "localField": "key1", 
        "foreignField": "key1", 
        "as": "coll2_doc"
    }}, 
    { "$unwind": "$coll2_doc" },
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$key2", "$coll2_doc.key2" ] }, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }}, 
    { 
      $project: {
         key1: 1, 
         key2: 1, 
         key3: 1, 
         key4: "$coll2_doc.key4",
         key5: "$coll2_doc.key5", 
         key6: "$coll2_doc.key6", 
         key7: "$coll2_doc.key7", 
         key8: "$coll2_doc.key8", 
     key9: "$coll2_doc.key9",  

      } 
    }, 
    {$out: "coll3"} 
], {allowDiskUse: true} );
```

and `db.coll3.find()` would return

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("588610ead0ae360cb815e55f"),
    "key1" : "115384042",
    "key2" : "276209",
    "key3" : "10101122317876",
    "key4" : 10,
    "key5" : 4,
    "key6" : 0,
    "key7" : "false",
    "key8" : 0,
    "key9" : "false"
}
```

### Edit: MongoDB 3.4 solution

If you don't want to specify all keys in the `$project` stage, you can take advantage of `$addFields` and `$replaceRoot`, two new operators introduced in MongoDB 3.4

the query would become:

```
db.coll1.aggregate([
    { "$lookup": { 
        "from": "coll2", 
        "localField": "key1", 
        "foreignField": "key1", 
        "as": "coll2_doc"
    }}, 
    { "$unwind": "$coll2_doc" },
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$key2", "$coll2_doc.key2" ] }, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }}, 
    {$addFields: {"coll2_doc.key3": "$key3" }},
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$coll2_doc"}},
    {$out: "coll3"} 
], {allowDiskUse: true})
```

Comment: in the `$project: ` part of aggregation, I need all keys in `coll2` plus `key3` from `coll1` - is there a way to specify this in a more simpler way than having to specify all keys from coll2 - that collection has 200 keys :(

Comment: I tried this , this works. However regarding the improvement in speed, the improvement I observed is from 15000 coll1 documents per hour using application code to 37000 coll1 documents per hour using mongoDb aggregate . Is this across the expected lines or is it taking too long ? To me, compared to typical RDBMS this is order of magnitude longer in terms of time to completion.

Comment: @user3206440 it's impossible to answer with the info you provided. It depends a lot on the hardware you're using (disk type, RAM...) and also on your collection content. You should take a look at the [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#example-aggregate-method-explain-option) of the query to better understand what happens

Comment: understand your point, however with the same machine is the performance numbers as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

After toying around this for sometime, realized that index were not added. Adding index reduces the query run time by orders of magnitude.

To add index, do the following.

```
db.coll1.ensureIndex({"key1": 1, "key2": 1});
db.coll2.ensureIndex({"key1": 1, "key2": 1});
```

Using index the overall query run time came to 1/10xxxxxxth of what it was earlier.

The learning is that while working with large data sets, index the fields used for `find` - that itself reduces query run time a lot.